Diode Substitution for monitor power supply
I am repairing a power supply for a monitor and need to replace a diode, the one is question is a B5100C from Diodes Inc.
I have an Onsemi FSV15150V, would this be OK as a substitute? From what I can gather from the datasheet it might work.


I would try it. Your biggest challenge would be the capsule and land pattern difference.
